# Is there way while we upgrade themes then over themes customisation will not be change?

Tags: cs-cart

When I changed or Update my current themes than my customization will not remain as it is. Is there any way where I can  override my changes to add-on and hook

Answer (score 0):

CS-Cart has thought of this. If you desire to preserve changes, take a look at the 'My Changes' addon, as it exactly fits your purpose: https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/user_guide/addons/my_changes/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this document: https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.4.x/designer_guide/parent_themes.html
CS-Cart has so called 'parent themes' it's mean when you make any design changes you should do them in child theme. In this case after upgrade you child theme changes won't be overwritten and will work correctly.
In default package of CS-Cart - Bright Theme works this way.

And yes, in case of code changes use My_changes addon or any custom add-on. More details here: https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/getting_started/guidelines.html